# show image in gtkmm from integer array

Tags: c++, image, widget, gtkmm

I have an integer array with a gray scale image and I need to show it in my application. I'm programing in C++ with gtkmm and I can't find any widget like a canvas that allow you to show and access each pixel in the image.

Comment: I had this same problem, couldn't figure it out (not that I tried too much either, was just trying to plot a mandelbrot for lulz). There are so many seemingly similar pixel buffers and the documentation is very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to use the following class with constructor:

```
Gdk::Bitmap::Bitmap(const char *data, int width, int height)
```

to create bitmap and load your data into it.

Later you can use Gdk::Pixmap or Gdk::Window to draw. There is also Pixbuf class to store pixels.

Comment: Bitmap is for black and white images, but I need grayscale; for this can be good Pixmap. But my trouble is that I need an easy and fast way to get and change pixel by pixel in te screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find a solution as well. The only way I found so far (using gtkmm-3.0) is to convert the grayscale image to RGB, pixel by pixel.

You allocate another data buffer three times as big as the original one. Then you copy each pixel from the original to the copy, three times. To create 1280*1024 (my case) pixbuf you can call:

```
Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(copy, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, 1280, 1024, 1280*3);
```

To access the pixels in the bitmap I suppose you can use `Gdk::Pixbuf::get_pixels()`.